# How to optimize invoice validation

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I'm working on database that uses lot of data. One invoice could have 7482 different articles. Validating invoice cost so much time, it took 26 minutes to validate one with 7482 articles. I find the method that take time to finish, it is the "action_move_create" inside "odoo\addons\account\models\account_invoice.py".

```
@api.multi
def action_move_create(self):
    """ Creates invoice related analytics and financial move lines """
    account_move = self.env['account.move']

    for inv in self:
        if not inv.journal_id.sequence_id:
            raise UserError(_('Please define sequence on the journal related to this invoice.'))
        if not inv.invoice_line_ids.filtered(lambda line: line.account_id):
            raise UserError(_('Please add at least one invoice line.'))
        if inv.move_id:
            continue


        if not inv.date_invoice:
            inv.write({'date_invoice': fields.Date.context_today(self)})
        if not inv.date_due:
            inv.write({'date_due': inv.date_invoice})
        company_currency = inv.company_id.currency_id

        # create move lines (one per invoice line + eventual taxes and analytic lines)
        iml = inv.invoice_line_move_line_get()
        iml += inv.tax_line_move_line_get()

        diff_currency = inv.currency_id != company_currency
        # create one move line for the total and possibly adjust the other lines amount
        total, total_currency, iml = inv.compute_invoice_totals(company_currency, iml)

        name = inv.name or ''
        if inv.payment_term_id:
            totlines = inv.payment_term_id.with_context(currency_id=company_currency.id).compute(total, inv.date_invoice)[0]
            res_amount_currency = total_currency
            for i, t in enumerate(totlines):
                if inv.currency_id != company_currency:
                    amount_currency = company_currency._convert(t[1], inv.currency_id, inv.company_id, inv._get_currency_rate_date() or fields.Date.today())
                else:
                    amount_currency = False

                # last line: add the diff
                res_amount_currency -= amount_currency or 0
                if i + 1 == len(totlines):
                    amount_currency += res_amount_currency

                iml.append({
                    'type': 'dest',
                    'name': name,
                    'price': t[1],
                    'account_id': inv.account_id.id,
                    'date_maturity': t[0],
                    'amount_currency': diff_currency and amount_currency,
                    'currency_id': diff_currency and inv.currency_id.id,
                    'invoice_id': inv.id
                })
        else:
            iml.append({
                'type': 'dest',
                'name': name,
                'price': total,
                'account_id': inv.account_id.id,
                'date_maturity': inv.date_due,
                'amount_currency': diff_currency and total_currency,
                'currency_id': diff_currency and inv.currency_id.id,
                'invoice_id': inv.id
            })
        part = self.env['res.partner']._find_accounting_partner(inv.partner_id)
        line = [(0, 0, self.line_get_convert(l, part.id)) for l in iml]
        line = inv.group_lines(iml, line)

        line = inv.finalize_invoice_move_lines(line)

        date = inv.date or inv.date_invoice
        move_vals = {
            'ref': inv.reference,
            'line_ids': line,
            'journal_id': inv.journal_id.id,
            'date': date,
            'narration': inv.comment,
        }
        move = account_move.create(move_vals)
        # Pass invoice in method post: used if you want to get the same
        # account move reference when creating the same invoice after a cancelled one:
        move.post(invoice = inv)
        # make the invoice point to that move
        vals = {
            'move_id': move.id,
            'date': date,
            'move_name': move.name,
        }
        inv.write(vals)
    return True
```

Could you suggest some solutions?

We suppose that the hardware is efficient to run odoo correctly.

Comment: Good question, and indeed there are some bottlenecks in this method. I think there is some issue about it in Odoo's Github, but i didn't find it yet.

Comment: @CZoellner thanks for the clue. Let me search on github. Don't hesitate if you have some suggestion

Comment: @CZoellner when profiling, I find that this instruction account_move.create(move_vals) take 98% of the time. Can I change it to raw sql instead of using ORM?

Comment: Maybe there is a field computation triggering which leads to a recomputation with all "new" move lines, which ofcourse will end ...well... in execution time hell. I'm not sure raw SQL will be so good, because of side effects.

Comment: On first check i see `_amount_compute()` and `_compute_matched_percentage()` and both will be called 28 million times each.

Comment: @CZoellner should I add with self.env.norecompute(): on those methods? Or in write() or create() methods of account.move

Comment: You can try it, but have to recompute them afterwards. There is an example anywhere in account module. Just search for `with self.env.norecompute():`

Comment: @CZoellner thanks, i will dig for that

Comment: @CZoellner make those changes : https://pastebin.com/VpgzpNZH but sadly didn't get any perfomance improvment.

Comment: That's what i would have tried, too :/

Comment: @CZoellner, after attempting to use thread and failed. I made it with raw sql

Comment: Hopefully without side effects :-D

Comment: @CZoellner, computed fields are being computed as expected but related fields are not triggered and I added them in "vals".

Answer (score 0):

I optimize it by using raw sql query. I made these codes in account.invoice model:
The first one is the definition of _mock_create_move_line (called in action_move_create).

```
    def _mock_create_move_line(self, model, values, move):
        bad_names = ["analytic_line_ids", "tax_ids", "analytic_tag_ids"]
        other_fields = [
            "currency_id", "debit", "credit", "balance",
            "debit_cash_basis", "credit_cash_basis", "balance_cash_basis",
            "company_currency_id", "amount_residual",
            "amount_residual_currency", "tax_base_amount", "reconciled",
            "company_id", "counterpart"
        ]
        cr = self.env.cr
        quote = '"{}"'.format
        columns = []
        columns1 = []
        for i, v in enumerate(values):
            v = model._add_missing_default_values(v)
            account_id = self.env['account.account'].browse(v['account_id'])
            # compulsory columns and some stored related columns
            # related fields are not triggered, krrrrr
            v.update({
                'move_id': move.id,
                'date_maturity': move.date,
                'company_id': account_id.company_id.id,
                'date': move.date,
                'journal_id': move.journal_id.id,
                'user_type_id': account_id.user_type_id.id,
                'create_uid': self.env.uid,
                'create_date': fields.Datetime.now()
            })
            ######
            temp_column = []
            for name, val in sorted(v.items()):
                if name in bad_names:
                    continue
                field = model._fields[name]
                if field.column_type:
                    col_val = field.convert_to_column(val, model, v)
                    temp_column.append(col_val)
                    if not i:
                        columns1.append((name, field.column_format, col_val))
            columns.append(tuple(temp_column))

        model.check_access_rule('create')

        try:
            query = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES {} RETURNING id".format(
                quote(model._table),
                ", ".join(quote(name) for name, fmt, val in columns1),
                ", ".join('%s' for fmt in columns),
            )
            cr.execute(query, columns)
            ids = cr.fetchall()
            # clear the model cache to take account of the new insertion
            # if not executed, relationnal field will not be updated
            model.invalidate_cache()

            account_move_line_ids = model.browse(ids)

            account_move_line_ids.modified(other_fields)

            account_move_line_ids.recompute()


            # update parent_path
            account_move_line_ids._parent_store_create()


        except Exception as e:
            _logger.info(e)
            cr.rollback()

        return
```

The second one is the overriding of native method action_move_create. I make some modification, call _mock_create_move_line if there is 'raw_sql' in the context.

```
@api.multi
def action_move_create(self):
    """ Creates invoice related analytics and financial move lines """
    # TODO : make choice between ORM or raw sql according to the context
    account_move = self.env['account.move']

    for inv in self:
        if not inv.journal_id.sequence_id:
            raise UserError(_('Please define sequence on the journal related to this invoice.'))
        if not inv.invoice_line_ids.filtered(lambda line: line.account_id):
            raise UserError(_('Please add at least one invoice line.'))
        if inv.move_id:
            continue

        if not inv.date_invoice:
            inv.write({'date_invoice': fields.Date.context_today(self)})
        if not inv.date_due:
            inv.write({'date_due': inv.date_invoice})
        company_currency = inv.company_id.currency_id

        # create move lines (one per invoice line + eventual taxes and analytic lines)
        iml = inv.invoice_line_move_line_get()
        iml += inv.tax_line_move_line_get()

        diff_currency = inv.currency_id != company_currency
        # create one move line for the total and possibly adjust the other lines amount
        total, total_currency, iml = inv.compute_invoice_totals(company_currency, iml)

        name = inv.name or ''
        if inv.payment_term_id:
            totlines = \
            inv.payment_term_id.with_context(currency_id=company_currency.id).compute(total, inv.date_invoice)[0]
            res_amount_currency = total_currency
            for i, t in enumerate(totlines):
                if inv.currency_id != company_currency:
                    amount_currency = company_currency._convert(t[1], inv.currency_id, inv.company_id,
                                                                inv._get_currency_rate_date() or fields.Date.today())
                else:
                    amount_currency = False

                # last line: add the diff
                res_amount_currency -= amount_currency or 0
                if i + 1 == len(totlines):
                    amount_currency += res_amount_currency

                iml.append({
                    'type': 'dest',
                    'name': name,
                    'price': t[1],
                    'account_id': inv.account_id.id,
                    'date_maturity': t[0],
                    'amount_currency': diff_currency and amount_currency,
                    'currency_id': diff_currency and inv.currency_id.id,
                    'invoice_id': inv.id
                })
        else:
            iml.append({
                'type': 'dest',
                'name': name,
                'price': total,
                'account_id': inv.account_id.id,
                'date_maturity': inv.date_due,
                'amount_currency': diff_currency and total_currency,
                'currency_id': diff_currency and inv.currency_id.id,
                'invoice_id': inv.id
            })
        part = self.env['res.partner']._find_accounting_partner(inv.partner_id)
        line = [(0, 0, self.line_get_convert(l, part.id)) for l in iml]
        line = inv.group_lines(iml, line)

        line = inv.finalize_invoice_move_lines(line)

        date = inv.date or inv.date_invoice

        if self.env.context.get('raw_sql', None):
            move_vals = {
                'ref': inv.reference,
                'journal_id': inv.journal_id.id,
                'date': date,
                'narration': inv.comment,
            }
            # remove (0, 0, ...)
            # override the group_lines method to avoid looping on next instruction
            new_lines = [nl[2] for nl in line]
            # TODO do not call compute here, add with ...norecompute()
            move = account_move.create(move_vals)
            move.env.cr.commit()

            self._mock_create_move_line(self.env['account.move.line'], new_lines, move)
            # Pass invoice in method post: used if you want to get the same
            # account move reference when creating the same invoice after a cancelled one:
            # compute move, it is not triggered automatically bc raw sql insertion
            # is it correct to call it like this ? find better way
            move._amount_compute()
            move._compute_partner_id()
            move._compute_matched_percentage()
        else:
            # make default behavior
            move_vals = {
                'ref': inv.reference,
                'line_ids': line,
                'journal_id': inv.journal_id.id,
                'date': date,
                'narration': inv.comment,
            }
            move = account_move.create(move_vals)

        move.post(invoice=inv)
        # make the invoice point to that move
        vals = {
            'move_id': move.id,
            'date': date,
            'move_name': move.name,
        }
        inv.write(vals)
    return True
```

Now, the execution time is less than 1 minutes for about 7000 records to insert inside invoice.move.line